# angularjs data binding with cache factory not working

Tags: angularjs, caching, data-binding, factory

take a look at this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XkVDNfVlaiHNHLSmxyy9?p=preview).  (data binding is happening in the names list but not in the movies list)

click a name on the list on the names:  the details are shown below.  If you edit the data in the details the list gets updated with data binding (as expected).

do the same with the list with movies, click on a movie, and edit the data in the details below. the list is not updating.

the only difference in the 2 factories is that the "Names" is from a static json file and the "movies" from a movie API.

this is my movies factory:

```
app.factory('moviesFactory', function($http) {
var cachedData;

 function getData(callback) {
if (cachedData) {
  callback(cachedData);
} else {
  $http.get('https://yts.re/api/list', {
    params: {
      quality: "3D",
      limit: 3
    }
  }).success(function(data) {
    cachedData = data.MovieList;
    callback(data.MovieList);
  });
}
  }
  return {
getAll: getData,
getOne: function(itemId, callback) {
  getData(function(data) {
    var movie = data.filter(function(entry) {
      return entry.MovieID === itemId;
    })[0];
    callback(movie);
  });
}
  };
});
```

the only difference in the names factory is this line:

```
$http.get('foo.json').success(function(data){...}
```

I don't understand why the names list works and the movies is not.

How can i make the movies detail data-bind with the movies list. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return updated data to the catched data then you will get updated data.  app.factory('moviesFactory', function($http) {
    var cachedData;

```
 function getData(callback) {
if (cachedData) {
  callback(cachedData);
} else {
  $http.get('https://yts.re/api/list', {
    params: {
      quality: "3D",
      limit: 3
    }
  }).success(function(data) {
    cachedData = data.MovieList;
    callback(cachedData);
  });
}
  }
  return {
getAll: getData,
getOne: function(itemId, callback) {
  getData(function(data) {
    var movie = data.filter(function(entry) {
      return entry.MovieID === itemId;
    })[0];
    callback(movie);
  });
}
  };
});
```

Comment: thanx, it worked.  do you know why it works with the json file but not with the api?  I don't understand.